# How to attach class to child element in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How can I attach class to image class, if I can only edit CSS and the image doesn't carry any unique class or id?

**id case**

```
<section id="unique-section-id">
  <img src="...">
</section>
```

**class case**

```
<section class="unique-section-class">
  <img src="...">
</section>
```

@Edit: I added "class case", as "id case" solution doesn't seem to work with classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the image just by its tag and the parent it's in since the parent has a unique ID:

```css
section#unique-section-id > img {
/* css */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy just put child element you wanna target after the parent element

for example

```
ul li{
background-color:red;
}
```

and in your class case is

```
.unique-section-class img{
///Any Css
}
```

Here '.' denotes class which is parent 
you can add as many child you want by just putting Space between them .Greater than or lower than sign is  not necessary